# Foundation Sticky plugin suddenly not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, sticky

For the longest time, the Foundation Sticky plugin was working as expected, sticking as the page scroll met the top of the sidebar. Now, suddenly, it's broken:

https://www.arcresources.com/about-arc/board-of-directors/member-bios

It jumps once, and the classes are changed, indicating the plugin is firing and adding the top margin, but after that, nothing.

I've tried commenting out all other JS, and relevant CSS to see if something was interfering, but the same problem persists.

Adding `width: 100%` and `position: fixed` to the data-sticky div produces the right results, but this is the code the Sticky plugin should be adding and removing based on my top and bottom anchors.

Sidebar code:

```
<div class="grid-container sidebar-nav-wrapper {{ firstSegment }}">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <nav data-sticky-container class="show-for-large large-3 large-offset-9 cell sidebar-nav">
            <div data-sticky data-top-anchor="main" data-btm-anchor="main:bottom" data-sticky-on="large" data-margin-top="6">
                <!-- Sidebar content -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: As a stopgap, I added width: 100% and position: fixed to the is-stuck class. This mostly works, except the sidebar no longer "freezes" at the bottom anchor, it just resets to the top. Too prevent this, I also changed the anchor to footer:bottom instead of main:bottom. Still no idea why the Sticky plugin suddenly stopped working.